How to solve this question about permutations, where my approach is wrong?
This a question from book "The Theory of Probability" by Santosh S. Venkatesh.
Let  $\pi_1,\pi_2,…,\pi_n$ be a random permutation of numbers $1…n$. If it is told that $\pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1}$ what is the probability that $\pi_k=n$.
My approach is, let us use Bayes theorem:
$$Pr\{ \pi_k=n |\pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}=\frac{ Pr\{\pi_k=n, \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}}{Pr\{ \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}}$$
Solving for numerator:
We want $\pi_k=n$, which means that previous $k-1$ positions can be filled using $n-1$ numbers giving ${}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$. Furthermore,  the total number of sequences that can be framed are $n!$. Giving us $Pr\{\pi_k=n, \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}={}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}/n!$
Solving for Denominator:
We want $Pr\{ \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}$, now we have to start with number $k$, because rest all will be smaller. If $\pi_k=k$ then we have a total of $k-1$ spaces to be filled by $1,...,k-1$ numbers so the total probability of such sequences is $(k-1)!/n!$. Now let us say that $\pi_k=k+1$, here we have a total of $k-1$ spaces to be filled by $k,k-1,...,1$ numbers. But the condition is that the sequence must have $k$, otherwise we will be counting a sequence twice. Therefore, total spaces are now $k-2$, to be filled by $k-1,...,1$ numbers. Moreover, depending on the position of $k$ the total number of sequences will be ${}_{k-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-2}\times(k-1)$ and the probability is ${}_{k-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-2}\times(k-1)/n!$   Generalizing we have:
$$=\frac{\frac{{}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}}{n!}}{\frac{(k-1)\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-2}{}_i\mathcal{P}_{k-2}}{n!}+\frac{(k-1)!}{n!}}{}$$
where ${h}\mathcal{P}_{g}=\frac{h!}{(h-g)!}$ is the normal permutation operator.
I know the answer is $k/n$, and is provided here but I want to know where my approach is lacking.
Edit: Earlier I was repeating the permutations. I have now rectified the same.

For the numerator, it should just be the probability that $\pi_k = n$, because this condition obviously implies that $\pi_k$ is greater than $\pi_j$ for all other $j$.

And for the denominator I don’t know where you’re getting your expression exactly but you just need the probability that $\pi_k$ is the greatest one out of $\pi_1,…,\pi_k$. This leads you straight to $(1/n)/(1/k)$

@SBK The condition is just that $\pi_k > \pi_j$ for $j < k$, not $\pi_k > \pi_j$ for all other $j$.

@SBK @ Jair Taylor I have tried to explain my point of view. Can you please tell where I am making mistake.

Since you asked to know what you did wrong, here is a list of the errors.

Solving for numerator:
We want $\pi_k=n$, which means that previous $k-1$ positions can be filled using $n-1$ numbers giving ${}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$.

Error number $1$.
You have ignored the fact that after selecting $k-1$ of the $n - 1$ numbers to fill the positions $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_{k-1}$, you must use the remaining $n - k$ numbers to fill the $n - k$ positions $\pi_{k+1},\ldots,\pi_n$. Those numbers also can be filled in in any order, giving $(n - k)!$ permutations. So the total number of permutations is
${}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}(n - k)! = (n - 1)!$.
You could also notice that you are putting $n - 1$ numbers in any order in $n - 1$ positions altogether (every position except $\pi_k$) and get $(n - 1)!$ permutations directly.

Furthermore,  the total number of sequences that can be framed are $n!$. Giving us $Pr\{\pi_k=n, \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}={}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}/n!$

Correcting the number of permutations from ${}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ to $(n - 1)!$
gives the result
$$Pr\{\pi_k=n, \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \} = \frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac1n.$$

Solving for Denominator:
We want $Pr\{ \pi_k>\pi_1,\pi_k>\pi_2,…,\pi_k>\pi_{k-1} \}$, now we have to start with number $k$, because rest all will be smaller. If $\pi_k=k$ then we have a total of $k-1$ spaces to be filled by $1,...,k-1$ numbers so the total probability of such sequences is $(k-1)!/n!$.

Error number $2$.
Again you ignored the remaining $n - k$ spaces can be filled with the remaining $n - k$ numbers in any order, so instead of $(k - 1)!$ permutations you have $(k - 1)!(n - k)!$
for a total probability of $$\frac{(k - 1)!(n - k)!}{n!}.$$

Now let us say that $\pi_k=k+1$, here we have a total of $k-1$ spaces to be filled by $k,k-1,...,1$ numbers. But the condition is that the sequence must have $k$, otherwise we will be counting a sequence twice.

Error number $3$.
In this part of the counting you must count all the sequences in which $\pi_k=k+1$. No other part of your "solving for the denominator" counts any of those sequences, because in every other part of that solution you set $\pi_k \neq k+1$.
Therefore when counting sequences for $\pi_k=k+1$ you must also count the sequences in which $k$ appears in one of the places $\pi_{k+1},\ldots,\pi_n$.

Therefore, total spaces are now $k-2$, to be filled by $k-1,...,1$ numbers. Moreover, depending on the position of $k$ the total number of sequences will be ${}_{k-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-2}\times(k-1)$

Error number $4$.
Yet again you forgot that there are still $n - k$ positions to fill with the $n - k$ remaining numbers in any order.
Correcting for error number $3$ there are ${}_k\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ ways to fill the positions $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_{k-1}$ and $(n - k)!$ ways to fill the positions $\pi_{k+1},\ldots,\pi_n$, altogether ${}_k\mathcal{P}_{k-1} (n - k)!$ sequences.

and the probability is ${}_{k-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-2}\times(k-1)/n!$   Generalizing we have:
$$=\frac{\frac{{}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}}{n!}}{\frac{(k-1)\sum_{i=k-1}^{n-2}{}_i\mathcal{P}_{k-2}}{n!}+\frac{(k-1)!}{n!}}{}$$

Possible error number $5$.
You seem not to have really thought through how to "generalize" the case $\pi_k=k+1$, since you didn't show what to do for any larger number in place $\pi_k$. For example, if $\pi_k=k+2$, do you think you still need to include $k$ in the first $k - 1$ places, or do you need to include $k + 1$ there?
But what really shows the failure to think this through is the case $\pi_k=n$,
which must be included in the denominator.
Your "generalization" counts $(k - 1){}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-2}$ sequences, whereas when you counted these same sequences for the numerator you counted
${}_{n-1}\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$.
But perhaps it's unfair to count this as an error, because it is really just compounding previous errors. If you had not made error number $3$ you might have been able to generalize correctly from the cases $\pi_k=k$ and $\pi_k=k+1$.
Correcting for the errors, the denominator becomes
$$ \frac{(n-k)! \sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1} {}_i\mathcal{P}_{k-1}}{n!}. $$
Now we come to the strategic error, which is following a particular method of enumeration to an end that is confusing to compute rather than choosing a different way of doing the enumeration in the first place.
But that's just saying you're better off to try to find one of the methods such as other answers use.

Numerator.
When you want to find
$$
\mathbf{P}(\pi_k = n\ \text{and}\ \pi_k > \pi_j\ \text{for}\ j = 1,...,k-1\},
$$
you have put an $n!$ in the denominator (of this probability, i.e. not of the whole Bayes expression). This suggests you are going to work out the numerator for this probability by counting all of the permutations of $1,\dots,n$ in which $\pi_k = n$ and $\pi_k > \pi_j$ for $j=1,\dots,k-1$. Since
$$
\pi_k = n\ \Longrightarrow \pi_k > \pi_j\ \text{for all}\ j,
$$
this is the same as just counting all of the permutations in which $\pi_k = n$. This is just $(n-1)!$ i.e. the number of ways of arranging $1,\dots,k-1,k+1,\dots,n$ in the first $n-1$ 'slots'.
If you only count the ways of arranging  the smaller set $1,\dots,k$ in the first $n-1$ slots then you conflate lots of arrangement. e.g. all of the permutations of the form $(1,2,3,\dots,k-1,\ast,,\dots,\ast,n)$ are conflated and together only add one to the total count.
Denominator.
For the denominator of $\mathbf{P}(\pi_k > \pi_j\ \text{for}\ j = 1,\dots,k-1)$ you've again put $n!$ in the denominator of the probabilities, so you want need to count all of the permutations of $1,..,n$ that satisfy the condition. You say that the probability of $\pi_k=k$ and $\pi_k > \pi_j$ for $j = 1,\dots,k-1$ is $(k-1)!/n!$. But you haven't counted all the ways of arranging all $1,2,...,k-1,k+1,...,n$, you just argued by talking about how many ways there are to place $1,...,k-1$. Do you see the difference?
To try to make your approach work you have to place $1,...,k-1$ in the first $1,...,\pi_k-1$ slots and place $k+1,...,n$ in the remaining $(n-k)$ slots. And then sum over the possible values of $\pi_k \in \{k,...,n\}$.
However, like I said already, you can instead recognise that what you are counting is now just $k$ permutations.
